# MySQL in() multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

the following works (array is filled in by another MySQL query):

```
$array=(1,4,5,6,8);
$query=SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN(".implode(",",$array)."
```

But how can I do the following?:

```
$array=(
array('Id'=>1, 'Detail1'=>$row['Detail1'], 'Detail2'=>$row['Detail2']),
array('Id'=>4, 'Detail1'=>$row['Detail1'], 'Detail2'=>$row['Detail2']),
array('Id'=>5, 'Detail1'=>$row['Detail1'], 'Detail2'=>$row['Detail2']),
array('Id'=>6, 'Detail1'=>$row['Detail1'], 'Detail2'=>$row['Detail2']),
array('Id'=>8, 'Detail1'=>$row['Detail1'], 'Detail2'=>$row['Detail2']),
);
$query=SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN(".implode(",",$array[]['Id'])."
```

So i need to get all the id's, how can I do that in this multidimensional array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just do something like this:

```
$id_list = array();

foreach($array as $item) {
 $id_list[] = $item['Id'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN(".implode(',',$id_list).")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$list = array_reduce($id_list,function($total,$cur_value){
     if(!is_null($total)) $total .= ',';
     return $total.$cur_value['id'];
  });
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN(".$list.")";
```